# NHibernate mapping xml data to database

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have xml files containing data that I wish to insert into my database using Nhibernate. I can write some Linq that will process my data and map it to my nhibernate objects but I was wondering if there was some way of doing this without the need to write the translator from XML to Nhibernate myself.

Am not sure if something exists along these lines or if anyone has written something in the past to get XML data into the database using NHibernate.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what your looking for:
http://markmail.org/message/3jkwktw6226357qs